# Jest test case not working correctly for vuejs method with debounce

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, lodash

I am using lodash debounce for vuejs method as below.  scope parameter in this method is for 'this' variable.

```
loadData: debounce((scope, url = '') => {
  if (scope.id) {
    if (url === '') {
      url = `search?id=${scope.id}`
    }

    service.load(url).then(() => {
      // success
    }).catch(() => {
      // API error  
    })
  }
}, 500)
```

I have written test case as below:

```
test('loadData method', async () => {
 jest.clearAllMocks()
 const scope = {
   id: 2
 })

 const spy = jest.spyOn(service, 'load')
 await wrapper.vm.loadData(scope,'')

 expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('search?id=2')
})
```

test case is failing because it is not able to invoke load method. can someone please guide.

Comment: It works as expected because it's debounced. Use Jest fake timer to skip 500 ms